# extract data in hive

Tags: hive, bigdata, hiveql

I have data in a hive table column as below:

`customer reason=Other#customer reason free text=Space#customer type=Regular#customer end date=2020-12-31 19:50:00#customer offering criterion=0#customer type=KK#Customer factor=0.00#customer period=0#customer type=TN#customer value=0#customer plan type=M#cttype type=KK#`

I want to extract data value 0 against customer value.

I tried below query but it is giving full 'customer value=0' but i want only 0.
Please suggest.

`select regexp_replace(regexp_extract(information,'customer period=[^#]*',0),'customer period=','') from detail;`

Comment: The data is a bit difficult to understand, as this is not a very common format. Are independent rows supposed to be separated by "#"? Is the data heterogeneous in terms of fields?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear at all. 
If you want to limit the output, use LIMIT 1 (where 1 is number of rows you want to limit to)

Answer (score 0):

Please give the following a shot,

---table creation----

create table ch7(custdetails map string,string>)

row format delimited

collection items terminated by '#'

map keys terminated by '=';

----data loading----

Load data local inpath 'your-file-location-in-local' overwrite into table ch7;

----data selection-----

select custdetails["customer value"] from ch7;

Hope this helps!!